# data.table option instead of loop

Tags: loops

I have a dataset like:

```
    ID  X   t1  t2
1   01  A   1   4
2   01  A   6   7
3   01  C   9   12
4   02  A   1   3
5   02  C   6   10
6   02  A   11  12
```

reproducible with: `data <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("01",3),rep("02",3)), x=c("A","A","C","A","C","A"), t1=c(1,6,9,1,6,11), t2=c(4,7,12,3,10,12))`

and I'd like to have data in this format:

```
    ID  t   X
1   01  1   A
2   01  2   A
3   01  3   A
4   01  4   A
5   01  5   A
6   01  6   A
7   01  7   A
8   01  8   A
9   01  9   C
10  01  10  C
11  01  11  C
12  01  12  C
13  02  1   A
14  02  2   A
15  02  3   A
16  02  4   A
17  02  5   A
18  02  6   C
19  02  7   C
20  02  8   C
21  02  9   C
22  02  10  C
23  02  11  A
24  02  12  A
```

reproducible with: `data_final <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("01",12),rep("02",12)), t = rep(1:12,2), x= c(rep("A",8),rep("C",4),rep("A",5),rep("C",5),rep("A",2)))`.

Mainly, I'd like to obtain a df (data_final) with one row for each t (for each ID), and the proper status X.

Any idea?

Comment: is `5   01  5   A` correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Even 16 02 4 A, 17 02 5 A. In data_final I want X started on t1 to go till t1 of the following row, regardless gaps in time. Mainly, t2 is useful only for the last row of each ID (not for the other rows). Is it clearer?

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate the logic behind t1 and t2, I thought I understood but your previous comment unfortunately didn't make it clearer to me

Comment: It is probably clearer not considering t2, but just t1. In data_final, for each ID, starting from the first status X (in data), the same status will be replicated in each following t, until the first status change, and so on. In data_final each ID will be replicated y times(one for each different t), where y is fixed (i.e. 12 rows)

Comment: Is it a bit clearer?